# I want to search all the images url from the Sd card

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite

so i wanted a simple program to insert all these url into SQLite database.

Comment: Scratch your head first for an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Every image in android is listed in media database. The only excluded images are in folders where exist `.nomedia` file. So you already have images listed in database.